# Spring Boot ExceptionHandler for MethodArgumentNotValidException in RestController never gets invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, exception

I'm using Spring Boot v2.2.10 and Spring v5.2.9. I've created a Rest controller with an `@Valid @RequestBody` annotation. The validation works fine (I get a `400 BAD REQUEST` response when submitting values outside of the constraints), but I don't like the default error message as it reveals too much of internals. Thus, I defined an `@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)` method, but this method never gets invoked.

This is the controller with the exception handler:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;


@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/data")
public class DataController {

    @PostMapping(path = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    private void postData(
            @PathVariable String id,
            @Valid @RequestBody MyDTO dto) {
        
        // DO SOMETHING

    }
    
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public List<String> handleValidationExceptions(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        System.out.println("Handling method argument not valid exception");
        return ex.getBindingResult()
            .getAllErrors().stream()
            .map(ObjectError::getDefaultMessage)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } 
}
```

The DTO:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter
public class MyDTO {
    
    @Max(value = 1, message = "Value should not be greater than 1")
    private float value;
    
}
```

I also tried to put the `ExceptionHandler` into an extra class:

```
// Imports

@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    // Same as before

}
```

As I've said, my `ExceptionHandler` never gets invoked. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can try to apply the same approach in this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

I got the same problem and I solved it like in the code below which is slightly modified version of the sample in the link.

I think the problem is in the return type of your handleValidationExceptions method. Instead of List you should use Map<>.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> handleValidationExceptions(
            MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
}
```

Because I used @ControllerAdvice instead of @RestControllerAdvice, I needed to return ResponseEntity type. And I determine the response type in my return like
`ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);` 
But if you want to use RestControllerAdvise annotation then you can directly return Map<> object and in this case you can keep using **@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)** over your exception handler method.
So try to apply the code in your GlobalExceptionHandler class.

Answer (score 4):

try extend from class ResponseEntityExceptionHandler and override handleMethodArgumentNotValid

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionController extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex,
        HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` from Spring MVC? I am not using Spring MVC in my project.

Comment: @AnjaM Spring Boot under the hood uses either Spring MVC or Spring WebFlux for web related things. In your code example it looks like you're using Spring MVC

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak Sorry, I'm a newbie so I don't know much about how it works. We use a lot of WebFlux in our project (although not in this particular Controller), and there is no Spring MVC in the `pom.xml`. When I insert `import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, Eclipse tells that it cannot resolve `org.springframework.web.servlet`. If I add Spring MVC to `pom.xml` and try to start the project, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `javax.servlet.ServletException`.

Answer (score 2):

In WebFlux, probably you can catch WebExchangeBindException instead of MethodArgumentNotValidException.

you can also take bindingResult from there.